# Is it possible to develop Qt Multi-touch Applications to run on Windows, Linux, Mac?

Tags: qt, cross-platform, multi-touch

If so, are there any platform specific code to be modified, or any other apparent issues observed?

Comment: Personally I would write a separate UI for keyboard/mouse than for multi-touch - a good multi-touch UI does not translate to a good keyboard/mouse UI.

Comment: Yes, creating separate UI does give the complete look of a multi-touch app. But apart from this are there any OS specific drivers to be taken care of, for example. Any other programmatic issues?

Answer (score 1):

QTouchEvent was added in Qt 4.6: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtouchevent.html

There are some examples of what Qt have done:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b749KvoX3w4

There are limitations in that the underlying windowing system needs to support this, such as Windows 7.